# Retrieving entities with related tables c# using REST API2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first

I am building a web API that is suppose to populate data from a linked child table using a where clause.
I have attempted using include() with where() as per eager loading but without success.

```
public IQueryable<Market> getAllActive()
    {
        return db.Markets.Where(c => c.IsActive == true).Include(d => d.TravelCentres.Where(e => e.IsActive == true));
```

}

On researching, there are recommendations that I use explicit loading but it keeps error about the need to cast the data type. I am lost of ideas at the moment and will appreciate any help. Here is my code:

```
private TravelCentresDbContext db = new TravelCentresDbContext();    
public IQueryable<Market> getAllActive()
        {
            //return db.Markets.Where(c => c.IsActive == true).Include(d => d.TravelCentres);
            var result = db.Markets
                .Where(c => c.IsActive == true)
                .Select(p => new
                {
                    Market = p.MarketId,
                    TravelCentres = p.TravelCentres.Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
                });
            return (IQueryable<Market>)result;
        }
```

> I get this exception message Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TravelCentres.Models.TravelCentre]]]'
>   to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[TravelCentres.Models.Market]'.
>
> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` is not an `IQuerytable<Market>`, it's an IQueryable of an anonymous type with properties `Market` and `TravelCenters`.  So `(IQueryable<Market>)result` is an invalid cast.  It would be advisable to create a model with `Market` and `TravelCenters` properties and then return that.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int MarketId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TravelCentre> TravelCentres { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
var result = db.Markets
            .Where(c => c.IsActive == true)
            .Select(p => new MyModel()
            {
                Market = p.MarketId,
                TravelCentres = p.TravelCentres.Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
            });

return (IQueryable<MyModel>)result;
```